# Lining up three Layers that use same Coordinate Reference System (CRS) in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, layers, borders

How do you make all borders of a layer equal? they should be equal but i don't know how, mCRS layer is all in philippine zone 5(EPSG:3125), with the same formula/equation, I'm new to QGIS and I'm using QGIS 2.4 Chugiak.

[image]

Comment: I wonder whether when the data for the separate layers was being create, if firstly a different boundary was used to clip the data to the province limits (the top layer looks like it uses a much simpler boundary) and secondly whether there was an issue with CRS or projection-on-the-fly at the point of clipping the data (so while your layers my share a CRS the error lies one or two steps higher up the chain).

Comment: I also added another shapefile on my project and it has the exact boundaries with an another shapefile(Isabela_LMU). The top layer is created from another site, and the last 2 layers(in the picture) doesn't have the same boundaries but ceated on the same website.